# iOS tap recognizer to catch all taps

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want a pretty simple thing - in my top controller (which is navigation controller) to set up a tap gesture recognizer which will catch all the taps everywhere on the view. Currently when I tap on a button the system is not even thinking to bother my recognizer (except the `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` delegate method, where I return `YES`). Instead, it just executes a button click. So I want to install "the strongest" recognizer on a view hierarchy no matter what.

Comment: When someone presses the button do you want the tap and the button to both fire?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html

Comment: Nope, only one is working at a time. In my case - I open a drawer which takes only part of the screen, the rest of the UI is below it. Then I tap outside the drawer and it closes. When there is a button in the layout below then it steals the tap from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try putting an empty UIView on top of all other views and add the UITapGestureRecognizer to it. We do something similar with help overlays. The biggest issue is figuring out how and when to ignore the touches so the underlying buttons get them when needed.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
    b.frame = CGRectMake(50,50, b.bounds.size.width, b.bounds.size.height );
    [self.view addSubview:b];

    UIView *invisibleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    invisibleView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [invisibleView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapHit:)]];
    [self.view addSubview:invisibleView];
}

-(void)tapHit:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap {
    NSLog( @"tapHit" );
}
@end
```